# Android PhoneGap app made in Eclipse won't run jQuery ajax call

Tags: ajax, eclipse, cordova

I have a barebones index.html, Anddroid Phonegap project in Eclipse that will not execute jQuery Mobile ajax calls.  LogCat displays the following messages and the app crashes
CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR! 
CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful.

Interesting facts:
1.) Eclipse installs and runs the app fine if I comment out the ajax call.  2.) I use the same ajax pattern in an .apk that I get by processing an html-css-javascript app through PhoneGap Build, and it works fine.

Details:
In Eclipse Juno, I have an Android PhoneGap project (it uses the ADT and cordova-1.9.0.jar) with an index.html file which incorporates the following .js files in the following order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/temp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

the temp.js file has this in it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var theUrl = 'http://www.myDomain.biz/WebServices/gg.svc/';
console.log("theUrl + GetHelpFile = " + theUrl + "GetHelpFile");
$('div#divTarget').html("theUrl + GetHelpFile = " + theUrl + "GetHelpFile");

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
cache: false,
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: theUrl + "GetHelpFile",
contentType: "text/plain",
success: function (theJson) {
var help_file = $(theJson);
$('div#divHelpFile').html(help_file);
},
error: function ($theData) {
var tt = $theData;
alert(tt);
}
});
});
```

The project has

- cordova-1.9.0.jar in its build path
- an AndroidManifest.xml file that
  has <application><activity>s for my .java file
  android:name=".java_activity" and for
  android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"

and all the <uses-permissions>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
```

the Run configuration I am using in Eclipse targets a 4.0 AVD and that all works fine.
When I comment out the ajax call, Eclipse creates the .apk file, opens the AVD, installs the app, and it runs fine.  Also, I made a website in IIS for the same index.html file, in the same directory, and the page loads in the browser and the ajax runs fine.

I increased the timeout period and that did not help

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
```

What do you think I need to do to get the ajax call to execute in my Eclipse-Android-PhoneGap project?

Thanks

Comment: Update: the app runs fine on my phone, but not in the AVD.  Both are indicating that they are running Android 4.0.3  I am using the AVD here at work and the environment here requires us to use a proxy.  In IE we do Tools/ Internet Options/ Connections/ LAN Settings/ Use a proxy server, and fill in the proxy server URL.  So I think the AVD is not using that so the network here won't let the ajax call proceed.  Also, I make the app in the AVD use http://localhost etc which is a url that returns what I want, but that doesn't help.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use different type of ajax call:

```
$.get('http://yourdomain.com/index.php', function (data) {
alert(data);
});
```

[phonegap android ajax call doesnt work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986082/phonegap-android-ajax-call-doesnt-work#comment15983889_11986082)
here is my solution.