# phonegap android ajax call doesnt work

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

Im trying to make ajax call from eclipse android emulator with phonegap platform and jquery library to my developing computer. Here is scenario my server is running on my computer the same for emulator. When I try to call with ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "http://10.4.40.235/API.public/index.php",
            success : function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
            }
 });
```

It doesnt work. I assume because of cross domain ajax request, but how can I do this. I also tried with 10.0.2.2 IP but it didnt work as well. Spent couple of hours and dont seem to get anywhere.... my emulator and server on pc are connected because if I go with browser to 10.4.40.235/API.public/index.php it works...

In LogCat I get following error:

```
WEb Console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected indetifier at: http://10.0.2.2/API.public/index.php?calback=jQuery[some numbers]
enter code here
```

Comment: Phonegap application doesn't suffer from cross domain problem, and is there any exception in your logcat console?

Comment: could you try escaping the URL: `encodeURI("http://10.4.40.235/API.public/index.php")`

Answer (score 0):

after 3 hours of working I got the solution...This is working for me

```
$.get('http://10.0.2.2/API.public/index.php', function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```